# webpack: is it possible to just compile SCSS into CSS?

Tags: css, webpack, sass, frontend

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/scss/screen.scss',

  output: {
    filename: 'screen.css',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [
          'style-loader',
            'css-loader',
            'sass-loader'
          ]
        },
      {
        test: /\.jpg$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader',
        ],
      },
    ]
  }
};
```

This is my `webpack.config.js`. When I try to compile the SCSS into CSS it creates the `screen.css` file without any complaints, but the `screen.css` contains javascript code (from one of the loaders I guess).

Is it even possible to use webpack when the project doesn't really have any javascript file? I just have SCSS Files and Images.

Answer (score 4):

You should build CSS files by [ExtractTextPlugin][1].

Btw, `entry` key is using only for js files. Webpack watch `imports` or `requires` from entry files and build them all in a single file (I could miss something)

You need to install `extract-text-webpack-plugin` and require it

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
```

Then update your loader

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: "style-loader",
      use: [{loader: 'css-loader'}, 
            {loader: 'sass-loader'}]
    })
  }
```

And plugins

```
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: 'styles.css'
    })
]
```

However, webpack require have some entry js file.
You can just add next code, but don't use this JS file

```
entry: './app.js',

output: {
    path: join(__dirname, '/build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
}
```

And read more about [entries][2]
[1]: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin
[2]: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/

Comment: Not related to extract-text-plugin, the problem **ivsterr** has related to the fact that webpack suppose to bundle js files, and if in that js files there are imports for sass file, it will apply the sass-loader.

Comment: sass imports in js files? Really ?

Comment: Yeap, why not?
You can use extract-text-plugin to extract the styles from the bundle, but that is not relevant to the issue here.

Comment: As I see he needs to build native css file with compiled styles from scss.
I gave him solution, how to do it and how all people do it. Why it is not relevant?

Comment: Cause, he complained that he got js inside his final `css` file, the reason for that is what I wrote, the entry point should be js file.

Comment: I was a little wrong. He can build css without ExtraTextPlugin, but, I think, he want to build it as css file.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with your `webpack.config` file is that you gave it an `scss` file as entry point.

Webpack suppose to bundle js files, therefore you need to specify some js file, there you can import a `scss` file.